# Method returning container for use in range-based for loop

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class that contains some standard container that I want to return in a method, like so (just an example):

```
class IntArray
{
public:
    IntArray(const vector<int>& vals) : vals(vals) {}

    const vector<int>& getValues() const { return vals; }
    vector<int>& getValues() { return vals; }

private:
    vector<int> vals;
};
```

I returned the vector by reference to avoid making a copy of it (I would rather not want to rely on RVO). I don't want to do it using OutputIterators, because I really want to keep it short with C++11 range-based for loops like so:

```
for (int val : arr.getValues()) {
    // Something
}
```

But say I want to change the type of the member variable to `list<int>`, then I would have to change the method's return type, too, which might lead to incompatibilities. I also don't want to implement `begin()` and `end()` methods because there might be more than one such container per class.

What would be the preferred way of doing this?

Comment: All classes supported by [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin)  and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end), or which have a `begin` and `end` member functions, will be supported by the [ranged-based `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). Of course this includes all [standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Comment: Why are you using this wrapper to begin with? Why not just return a sequence<T> where sequence<T> wraps the vector<> or list<> and provides the .begin() and .end() methods?

Comment: There's a good article on exactly that problem [here](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html).

Comment: @Michael: IntArray is just an example here. In reality, I'm using things like meshes that might contain both submeshes and textures, for example. And introducing a class that just wraps these two containers seems a bit heavy to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a `typedef` and refer to that in your function signatures:

```
class IntArray
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<int> Vec;

    IntArray(const Vec& vals) : vals(vals) {}

    const Vec& getValues() const { return vals; }
    Vec& getValues() { return vals; }

private:
    Vec vals;
};
```

Now if you want to change the storage type, you just change the typedef:

```
typedef std::list<int> Vec;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generalise this with your own template:

```
template<typename CONTAINER>
class IntArray
{
    typedef CONTAINER<int> Vec;
public:
    IntArray(const Vec& vals) : vals(vals) {}
    const Vec& getValues() const { return vals; }
    Vec& getValues() { return vals; }

private:
    Vec vals;
};
```

Now you can specify the container type at will:

```
std::list<int> vals { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
IntArray<std::list> arr(vals);
for(int val: arr) {
    // Something
}
```